# How to hide pagination if there is only one or few page result?

Tags: php, wordpress

My page has 9 result per page and shows a pagination from 1-5, my problem is how can I hide the pagination number if the result of what I search is one or few entry result?

Sorry If I will not post all my code and thank you for helping me.

sidebar.php

```
<div class="side-box-select cf">
<div class="side-select">
<select name="unit_size_x" class="side-box__select">
    <option value="0" selected>Minimum</option>
    <option value="10">10sqm</option>
    <option value="20">20sqm</option>
    <option value="30">30sqm</option>
    <option value="40">40sqm</option>
    <option value="50">50sqm</option>
    <option value="60">60sqm</option>
    <option value="70">70sqm</option>
    <option value="80">80sqm</option>
    <option value="90">90sqm</option>
    <option value="100">100sqm</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="side-select">

<select name="unit_size_y" class="side-box__select">
    <option value="10">10sqm</option>
    <option value="20">20sqm</option>
    <option value="30">30sqm</option>
    <option value="40">40sqm</option>
    <option value="50">50sqm</option>
    <option value="60">60sqm</option>
    <option value="70">70sqm</option>
    <option value="80">80sqm</option>
    <option value="90">90sqm</option>
    <option value="100">100sqm</option>
   <option value="101" selected>Maximum</option>

</select>
</div>
```

search.php

```
$metaquerysp[] = array(
'key'=>'unit_size',
'value'=>array( $unit_size_x, $unit_size_y ),
'compare'=>'BETWEEN',
'type'=>'NUMERIC',
);
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'orderby' => 'DATE',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => $metaquerysp
     );?>
```

Comment: You seem to have 9 posts per page. So check if there are 9 or fewer results - then hide the pagnation.

Comment: edit your code with  a while loop in it .. so i will give you an accurate answer

Comment: You can check if post is more then 9 then pagination is display otherwise hide it.

Comment: Even i search only 7 results that needs to display 1 page why do i get the max number of pages which is 5 pages?

Comment: Here is a sample of my query [link](http://c-net-ph.com/property/?s&catnum=condominium&unit_size_x=40&unit_size_y=50&low=0&high=9999999) notice that I only get 7 results but still displaying 5 pages

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will make sense. Check `$query->post_count` for the number of posts returned by your query.

```
$paged          = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// Posts per page
$posts_per_page = 9;
// Should pagination show (default yes)
$pagination     = true;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'DATE',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => $metaquerysp
);

// Run query
$query =  new WP_Query($args);

// If query has less than $posts_per_page results, no pagination
if($query->post_count<$posts_per_page) {
    $pagination = false;
}

// The loop
if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();

        // Stuff
    }
}

if($pagination) {
    // show pagination
}
```